# I can't find my android app in google play store by name searching

Tags: android, mobile-application, google-play-console

I published android app. But I can't find my app by name searching in Google Play Store.
But the app is exist in play store. I can see my app with url directly.
I don't know why can't find my app.
Please advance me if any know the reason.

Comment: if search by package name?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, can't find app with package name.

Comment: @WaterFlower I think only the top 200 (or 250?) are showed. Your keyword should be a red ocean.

Comment: @hata valid reason.

Comment: For a bit of context, apps that are published to the Play Store always take at least a little bit of time to be "indexed," which is when Google crawls an app's title and listing to pull relevant names and keywords that dictate how the app surfaces in search

Comment: Hi @KasımÖzdemir Thanks for your reply. So you mean I need to wait? If so, how much?

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't know, Google knows.

Answer (score 1):

One **short term** solution - Search app name (`<name>` in config.xml) within double quotes (for eg. "Foo Bar"). You would see your app, after the more popular/indexed apps with the same name.

For **long term**, customer/user friendly solution, you need to perform some ASO.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below link with the app package in the web browser.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.app.package.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me.

My app was firstly deployed for internal testing then I uploaded it to closed testing. Because I still had that internal testing track active I couldn't see my app by name searching.

What you should do is to **Pause** that internal track.

Then you should see your app. Good luck!